# Scala -> Function

Tags: scala

Looking at the following [Scala in Depth](http://www.manning.com/suereth/) code, what does `handle -> callback` mean?

```
trait Observable {
  type Handle
  def observe(callback: this.type => Unit): Handle = {
    val handle = createHandle(callback)
    callbacks += (handle -> callback)
    handle

  [code omitted]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`->` ultimately comes from [scala.ArrowAssoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef%24%24ArrowAssoc). scala.Predef also defines:

```
@inline implicit def any2ArrowAssoc[A](x: A): ArrowAssoc[A] = new ArrowAssoc(x)
```

which causes an implicit conversion of Any to an ArrowAssoc. This has the effect of adding ArrowAssoc's `->` method to all objects (because all objects inherit from Any).

As to what `->` *does*, it merely returns a Tuple2 of the two parameters. Or to put it another way, `(handle -> callback)` is more or less identical to `(handle, callback)`.

Although you've deleted the definition, `callbacks` is probably a `mutable.Map` object. `+=` adds (or updates) an entry in said map associating `handle` to `callback`. So basically, this appears to be adding the newly-created handle and the callback to a map of callbacks.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason (besides style) for using `(handle -> callback)` rather than `(handle, callback)`?

Comment: `scala.collection.Map` has a method `+` which takes an arbitrary number of arguments. Calling it this way: `map + (key, value)` can be interpreted as trying to add two entries `key` and `value` and then failing due to not being of the right type. Also, `->` does not need parentheses.

Comment: The `->` syntax is just for convenience with maps, you can see it as an arrow to associate a key with a value. Makes this syntax, for example, easy to read: `val m = Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two', 3 -> "three")`

Answer (score 1):

Handle is an "abstract type". It must be defined in a concrete subclass.

callback is a function that takes a (this.type) and returns nothing (Unit).

The -> syntax is just alternate syntax for a tuple:

(3 -> "abcd") is the same as (3, "abcd")